# Is it possible to find the nth term of this recursive sequence?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have the following sequence:
$$x_n= y - sgn(x_{n-1}) \cdot |b\cdot x_{n-1} - c|^{0.5}$$
$$x_1=0$$
Is there a way to find $x_n$ without knowing $x_{n-1}$?

Comment: What are $y,x,b,c$?  Shouldn't $x_{n-1}$ appear somewhere on the right hand?  What's the point of specifying that $x_n=x_n$?

Comment: @lulu Sorry, some formatting issues on my part. $y,b,c$ are arbitrary integer constants.

Comment: And what's $x$?

Comment: @lulu Wow, I'm really out of sorts today, sorry. I'm copying this over from a language in which I don't have to specify 'x(n-1)', and forgot to add it to the x's. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Makes sense now...looks like it is eventually periodic (period $2$). Or at least that it converges to a 2-cycle. Not immediately sure why...

Comment: So this is kind of a nested radical. I don't think it's possible to create a compact expression for $x_n$. The limit of the sequence is possilbe to find, on the other hand